# How can I know whether a class is inherited from another one? Some methods like is_a?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

Simple example:

```
class A
end

class B < A
end
```

Then, how can I judge whether class B is inherited from class A?
Is there a method somehow like `is_a?` or maybe called `is_child_of?`?

I can't find one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `<` operator:

`B < A` will be true, if B is a subclass of A.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby the class `Object` has a `kind_of?` method that does what you want. This is also aliased to `is_a?`:

```
module M; end
class A
  include M
end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end
b = B.new
b.kind_of? A   #=> true
b.is_of? B     #=> true
b.kind_of? C   #=> false
b.kind_of? M   #=> true
```

Also, the class `Class` has a `superclass` method:

```
>> B.superclass
=> A
```

Note that you can find out what methods any object supports by asking it:

```
B.methods.sort
```

The output from this command would have included the `kind_of?`/`is_a?`/`superclass` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the method definitions for Ruby [Objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000372) online.

The closest useful method would be `is_a?` or `kind_of?` however read the documentation to be sure they are what you're looking for.